# Greatest product of four adjacent numbers in a grid (#11 Euler)

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are already many questions on stackoverlow regarding question 11 of Euler project. However I would like to figure out what is the mistake in **my code**.

Here is the python code:

```
    a=[['08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08'],
   ['49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00'],
   ['81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65'],
   ['52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91'],
   ['22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80'],
   ['24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50'],
   ['32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70'],
   ['67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21'],
   ['24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72'],
   ['21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95'],
   ['78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92'],
   ['16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57'],
   ['86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58'],
   ['19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40'],
   ['04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66'],
   ['88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69'],
   ['04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36'],
   ['20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16'],
   ['20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54'],
   ['01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48']]

b=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append(a[i][0].split(' '))

Sum=1
currentSum=1

#Loop for checking horizontally adjacent sum
for x in range(20):
    for y in range(16):
        for z in range(4):
            currentSum*=int(b[x][y+z])
        if currentSum>Sum:
            Sum=currentSum
        currentSum=1

#Loop for checking vertically adjacent sum
for x in range(0, 16):
    for y in range(0, 20):
        for z in range(0, 4):
            currentSum*=int(b[x+z][y])
        if currentSum>Sum:
            Sum=currentSum
        currentSum=1

#Loop for checking diagonally adjacent sum (\)
for x in range(0, 16):
    for y in range(0, 16):
        for z in range(4):
            currentSum*=int(b[x+z][y+z])
        if currentSum>Sum:
            Sum=currentSum
        currentSum=1

#Loop for checking diagonally adjacent sum(/)
for x in range(3, 20):
    for y in range(3, 20):
        for z in range(4):
            currentSum*=int(b[x-z][y-z])
        if currentSum>Sum:
            Sum=currentSum
        currentSum=1
        
print(Sum)
```

**My approach to the question:**

I had manually made the grid provided into a 20 x 1 2D list. However since I need a 20 x 20 2D list, I created a new one wherein the inner list items are the results of split function upon the first list items.

I have four nested loops, each for checking the products in one of the directions mentioned

The final answer yielded is **`51267216`**, which according to Project Euler is wrong.
I would like to know where I am going wrong, and some guidance in this direction without revealing the answer itself.

Another thing to note is I am trying to get this solved without any additional libraries like numpy.

Comment: It is easier for us if every question is self-containing. In that way we do not need to search for other information in other places. Could you provide a quick summary of your task with respect to the summation in different directions? Also could you provide the expected answer?

Comment: Project Euler discourages disclosing answers to ones who haven't completed them. I will also try adding what logic I'm using here

Comment: It seems the correct answer is `70600674`

Comment: It seems to me that you are early terminating on the edges. For example if we take the first four elements. What should the total sum? I assume this should be the product of `08 02 22 97` + product of `08 02 22` + product of  `08 02` + `08`.

Comment: When solving this problem, I also initially derived the same incorrect answer as you .   When examining my first solution, I noticed that while I was searching down and to the left and on the diagonal going from left to right, I failed to examine the diagonal going from right to left.  Fixing this issue resulted in the correct answer.  I would also suggest you look at ways to solve the problem with a single pass through the starting grid, rather than separate loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally figured out the mistake - the problem has arisen due to the use of incorrect indexing formula in the last for loop.

The correct code is:

```
#Loop for checking diagonally adjacent sum
for x in range(0, 16):
    for y in range(3, 20):
        for z in range(4):
            currentSum*=int(b[x+z][y-z]) //originally: b[x-z][x-y]
        if currentSum>Sum:
            Sum=currentSum
        currentSum=1
```

`b[x+z][y-z]` instead of `b[x-z][y-z]`

To add on, here are the pictorial representations of all four loops:

1st Loop:
[image]

2nd loop:
[image]

3rd Loop:
[image]

4th loop:
[image]